# Manipulating UILabels' text that's been added to the view programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, uilabel

I'm having trouble changing the text of an array of `UILabel`s. The labels were added programmatically and show in the view correctly.

I recursively make labels, set the default text and color of each, add each to an `NSMutableArray`, then add each `NSMutableArray` element to the view.

UPDATE:

I've found that when I called the method that updates the `UILabel`s from within the class, it works now.

The problem is, this view is in a `UIScrollView` and the button to change it is within the view that contains its instance. If I call it from that view, via a button click, an `NSLog` alert tells me that method is actually being executed, BUT the labels don't change.

Comment: `UITextField` and `UILabel` are not the same thing. Which do you have?

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant UILabel. I've successfully added the UILabels to an array now, then added them to the view by directly referencing the corresponding array element. But I am still having a problem with the above code (changing the text).

Comment: The problem here may be due to the fact that you first put the labels into an array, and then add the objects in the array to the view. Can you post the relevant code where you add the labels to the array and then the contents of the array to the view?

Comment: Hello Derek. Could you try the following line and see if it works? [[labels objectAtIndex:i] performSelectorOnMainThread : @selector(setText:) withObject:@"Testing" waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: This one is going to be hard to answer without seeing your code. Drop in the relevant chunk and it might be an easy catch. Kevin's answer below seems extremely plausible, though.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. And that line does nothing. The app still runs like normal.

Comment: OK Danilo, I will update my question to include more code chucks. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your array is actually nil. If that's the case, `[labels objectAtIndex:i]` is evaluating to nil, and you aren't actually doing anything. This would also explain why you couldn't add the label to the array, pull it back out of the array and add it to the view.

Comment: Kevin, I've fixed the error in my coding by cleaning it up a bit. The array now points to the appropriate UILabel. Example NSLog for object at index 0: <UILabel: 0x6d78380; frame = (20 20; 135 100); text = 'Test'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6d78460>>